# What is the best way to parse HTML pages for the author of an article/comment/post, etc?

Tags: html, parsing, author

Is there some universal, or more general method for parsing HTML pages to extract author names and info?

One approach would be to parse the HTML page for keywords such as "author", "user", "byline," etc. but this doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: What language did you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of the fact that many websites specifically call out information like this by annotating the html tags which contain it.

The reason they do this is to help google better understand the data, however there's nothing stopping you using it too.

Take a look at http://schema.org/ and you'll find the full documentation.

Tags with the following attribute: itemprop="author" indicate they contain the author of something (it's scoped by an itemscope attribute on a parent element)